# Importing specific columns from a CSV into excel

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to do what the title says and also do it for new records. I cannot link the CSV file because it exceeds the 255 limit. So i am attempting to split up the table.
I have the below table in access

| DateOfTest | Time | PromptTime | TestSequence | PATResults | Logs | Serial Number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |

Obviously, where the numbers are i want the data from the CSV to be inserted.
I have created a form including a button so i can run some VBA, but i cannot find the correct information online for my work, as i am new to VBA it is also a bit confusing.

I have attempted some random code, but i was just spraying and praying at that point

Comment: Your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72016627/make-linked-table-a-local-table-using-vba)  indicates that you have solved the linking problem - so this is no longer an issue?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question. In the impoer tool you can choose columns, but if you want to do it with a script, I would suggest to perform pre-processing phase with simple python and pandas to read the csv file, remove any unwanted columns and save to another CSV to be uploaded directly to excel.
something like this

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv ('csvfile.csv')
df.drop('column_name', inplace=True, axis=1)
df.to_excel ('filename.xlsx', index = False, header=True)
```

Comment: As new test data is appended to all these columns, i am trying to split the CSV in access itself.

Comment: The test data goes years back too. So it will be a lot of manual work to split the CSV